# How to easy extract data from nested collections?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

I use many-to-many relationships in Laravel.

In result I get collection with nested relations like this:

```
User->categories->announcements
```

How to get easy last nested collection `announcements`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use nested `foreach` loops. For example, if user is just one here (and not a collection of users):

```
@foreach ($user->categories as $category)
    @foreach ($category->announcements as $announcement)
        {{ $announcement->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: But do you agree that this is afwul to use so much loops. From another side I can not find another way, when I use many-to-many relationships

Comment: @Darama it's no awful, just use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) to load the data before using loops.